# How to countdown this schedule?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, schedule, countdowntimer

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime

scheduleTime = input('Scheduled time: (00:00:00 format)  ')

def time_scheduler():
    
    format = '%H:%M:%S'
    currentTime = datetime.today()
    time1 = datetime.strptime(scheduleTime, format) - datetime.strptime(str(currentTime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')), format)
    
    print(time1)


time_scheduler()
```

Code currently displays the time difference from the scheduled time to the current local time on the computer.

However, I need it to countdown the time difference that prints but have no clue how

I did a while true loop and it was counting down technically but it spammed the terminal with thousands of lines of code

Comment: Looks like "solve this instead of me".

Comment: @AbrahamTugalov I’m a beginner programmer who has looked at numerous resources and cannot figure out a solution to an issue I’m having. As a last resort, I came here. If you do not want to help solve, that’s fine, but being rude is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Use the while true loop and add `time.sleep(1)`

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I’m trying to have it work as a counter, all on a single line. Time sleep just brings it to a new line for the countdown.